# Loading Images from Web Directory, display in ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am trying to write a simple application that loads images that are stored in a web directory I've created. I want the application to grab ALL of the images that are stored in said directory and display them in a layout.

The code below works for only certain type of URLs(mainly tinypic, but not photobucket, imageshack etc) and also not for directories.

I've my image names formatted in sequence like `image1.png, image2.png`, etc. so that the code snippet and the `downloadFile()`-method would work.

But, I'm not sure how I would grab all the images from the server simultaneously because this only grabs one image at a time, sets it as a bitmap and then displays it in an IV. I'm pretty new to Android so some help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
public class NewWallpapersActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imView1;
    String imageUrl="http://i133.photobucket.com/albums/q44/slimjady/Wallpapers";
    Random r= new Random();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newwallpapers);

        Button bt3= (Button)findViewById(R.id.get_imagebt);
        bt3.setOnClickListener(getImgListener);
        imView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.IV1);
    }    

    View.OnClickListener getImgListener = new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View view) {
            //i tried to randomize the file download, in my server i put 4 files with name like
            //png0.png, png1.png, png2.png so different file is downloaded in button press
            int i =r.nextInt(4);
            downloadFile(imageUrl+"png"+i+".png");
            Log.i("im url",imageUrl+"png"+i+".png");
        }

    };

    Bitmap bmImg;

    void downloadFile(String fileUrl){
        URL myFileUrl = null;          
        try {
            myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            imView1.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String exception = "Erro: An Exception Was Thrown";
            Toast errortoast = Toast.makeText(this, exception, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            errortoast.show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some thoughts on this one:

### Displaying all Images

Since you want to display all Images from within a single folder, I would suggest you to have a `Directory`-Activity, which displayes all the images in the given directory and one `Image`-Activity which displays only one single Image.

To proper present this I would suggest [using a `GridView`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) to display all the Images and a normal Activity with a full-screen `ImageView` to display the single Image.

You could also [use the `Gallery`-widget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) to "combine" both those ideas.

### Not letting the user wait

One of the bigger problems with your approach is, that the images are getting downloaded on the [UI-Thread](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Depending on the size of all or on single image and the available connection-speed, Downloading the image can take a while. While the images are getting downloaded, the UI-Thread will wait for your `downloadStuff()`-method to return and the UI will freeze. This might create the illusion that your App just crashed.

So, you'll want to do the downloading in a separate thread. Android has a handy wrapper for this called an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

As a little bonus to show your user that the process might take a while you can use a [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) to illustrate this (on the UI-Thread).

### Knowing whats in a directory

Now we come to the point where we have to face some limitations. If you want to use Picture-Hosters like the ones you listed above, you'll need to check if they offer you an API (or something equal) to get a list of Images (or their URLs) from a certain directory/album (look for a "API"-link on the front-page).

If you host the images on your own Server, you should be able to create a little PHP-script (or whatever script/programming language you prefer), which then lists all image-files in the directory and presents them in an easy-to-parse way (either [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)).

This should enable you to get a list of URLs to the Image-files you want to display.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in depth response brother. But a quick question on the directory issue. I see why I would have to create a directory activity that would use the API to get all of the files/urls, but would I then call this Activity using the AsyncTask option you mentioned? I will b sure to go through all the links you suggested, that's a sea of resources there! Thanks again, man

Comment: No, you would actually start the downloading of the Images in an `AsyncTask` when the Activity is opened (in the `onStart()`-method for example). You can update your UI from an `AsyncTask`, an example might be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)